# how to remove the gray border at the time the pdf is loaded on uiwebview in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

Thought this question is asked many a time, I had to ask this question again as did not get any specific answer. While loading the PDF file using UIWebView, i get a gray border surrounding the pdf file which i want to remove.

Can anybody help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously not supported by the SDK. If you don't like the way `UIWebView` renders a PDF file, you will have to render it yourself using `CGContextDrawPDFPage()`.